# Mocking Authentication

Tags: spring, mockito

How do you mock `auth` in the code below?

Do you need to start with the `SecurityContextHolder` or can you just inject the fake `auth` somehow?

```
    if (success != null) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth.isAuthenticated()) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
```

---

Edit:

I went with Ralphs first solution in this case. Serges solution seems generally applicable though. Here's the tested code:

```
final Authentication auth = mock(Authentication.class);
when(auth.isAuthenticated()).thenReturn(true);

SecurityContextHolder.setContext(new SecurityContext() {

    @Override
    public Authentication getAuthentication() {
        return auth;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAuthentication(Authentication auth) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that is is hard to mock static method invocation, but you have different way to deal with this specific security context problem

**first way**: set the `AuthenticationToken` in your test

```
 @Test
 public void testSomething() {

    try{
       SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
          .setAuthentication(new TestingAuthenticationToken(login, null));

       //invoke test object

     finally {
         SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();         
     }
 }
```

---

**second way:** Inject a mock in the SecurityContextHolder

When you want to have more control for an example by an Mock for `SecurityContext`, then you can do:

```
 SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName("com.test.MyStrategy")
```

Then you need a Class `MyStrategy` that implements `SecurityContextHolderStrategy` and return you mocked SecurityContext for `SecurityContext getContext()`

---

**third way:** Inject a mock in the SecurityContext.setContext

Comment: That took care of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Edit : see below

You a calling a static method than cannot be mocked directly with `Mockito`. You can use PowerMock combined with Mockito to do it.

If it a really exceptional in your tests, you can cheat by creating a local class `SecurityContextHolder` (don't forget to remove the corresponding import ...) :

```
class SecurityContextHolder {
    static Authentication auth;

    static SecurityContext getContext() {
        return new SecurityContext {
            public Authentication getAuthentication() {
                return auth;
            }
            public void setAuthentication(Authentication auth) {
                this.auth = auth;
            }
            }();
        }
    }
}
```

and put a `mock(Authentication.class)` in it.

EDIT :

No need for a special class (thank to Ralph for the idea). Just call :

```
final Authentication auth = mock(Authentication.class);
SecurityContextHolder.setContext(new SecurityContext {
        return new SecurityContext {
            public Authentication getAuthentication() {
                return auth;
            }
            public void setAuthentication(Authentication auth) {
                this.auth = auth;
            }
});
```

Beware : I currently have no usable dev system and could not even test syntax, but the princip should work.

Comment: Added a tested version of your code to the question. Thx. :)